# How to get count of Selenium XPath results

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

As of now I am getting the count of the number of matching results using `listChanges.size()` . How do I directly get the count without loading `getChanges` in the list?

```
By getChanges = By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-addition') or contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-deletion')]");

List<WebElement> listChanges = driver.findElements(getChanges);
```

I found this([Count function in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985453/count-function-in-xpath?rq=1)) and I tried the below which does not work!

```
Integer getCount = By.xpath(count("//td[contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-addition') or contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-deletion')]"));
```

Looks like I have to do something like this.

```
Integer getCount = By.xpath("count(//td[contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-addition') or contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-deletion')])");
```

But the right hand side returns an object of type `By`

Comment: can you provide me the `url` to the site you are using if possible?

Comment: @Saifur : https://github.com/SunriseSoftVN/qlkh/commit/3aa0e16944e2552a7863941f683f26c571cd464e#diff-33c32c1890dcfb06827b5db4bee85959

Comment: So, what are you trying to accomplish there? Just to find out how many matching elements that `xpath` returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alex says, `size()` is the way to go. However I do have another suggestion for you.
Even though the proper way to find the element counts is to use `WebDriver` api with `findElements()` as per my knowledge. Another way is to execute `javascript` by using `executeScript()` and with proper `script`. I am not sure if `javascript` and `xpath` can be mixed together to accomplish this since `xpath` execution through `javascript` is not multi-browser right now. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-in-javascript). However, I do think using `cssSelector` with `javascript` can make it lot easier to accomplish. See the following code :

```
String cssQuery = ".blob-code-addition, .blob-code-deletion";
String script = "return document.querySelectorAll('" + cssQuery + "').length;";
Object count = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);

System.out.println(count);
```

**Print**

> 26

Comment: okay!  @Saifur If I could use count with XPATH, it could help me remove the processing associated with this statement. List<WebElement> listChanges = driver.findElements(getChanges);  thanks. I will check the above script as well and mark the answer.

Comment: @Zack As I said, `List<WebElement> listChanges = driver.findElements(getChanges); listChanges.size();` is the right way. But the above script does the samething and the `cssSelector` is written to replace the `xpath` you are using

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the count using `XPath`, because an xpath expression in selenium *has to correspond to an actual element on a page*.

The way you are doing it via `findElements()` + `size()` is how you have to count elements using the selenium webdriver.